# How to do that exercise, I don`t know even how to start

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the product probability space (($\Omega$$_{0}$,$\Sigma$$_{0}$)$^\mathbb{Z})^d$, $\mu$). Let $f$, $g$ be real
valued random variables. Assume f is $\Sigma$$_{I}$-B measurable. Then the following relation holds
$\int f \cdot g  d\mu$ = $\int f \cdot E_{I^c}(g)\cdot   d\mu|\Sigma_{I}$

where $\mu$$\Sigma$$_{I}$ denotes restriction of µ to $\Sigma$$_{I}$

I have no idea of how to try this exercise, could anybody help me please? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is $I$ a subset of $\Omega_0^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ and a member of $\Sigma = \Sigma_0^{\otimes \mathbb{Z}^d}$? In that case the relation  you have stated seems be a consequence of the tower property of conditional expectation: $$ E_{\mu}(fg) = E_{\mu}[E[fg| \Sigma_I]] =E_{\mu}[fE(g|\Sigma_I)].$$ If additionally it is given that $g$ is independent of $\Sigma_I$, then $E(g|\Sigma_I) = E(g)$ and you get your expression.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what's going on.